# How to unlisten an event in OpenLayers 4?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, events

I am trying to suppress the single click event that adds popups to the map. I have the following function:

```
function addFullScreenPopups(){
      map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup({insertFirst: false});
        map.addOverlay(popup);
        var prettyCoord = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'), 2);
        console.log("Pretty Coordinates : "+prettyCoord);
        popup.show(evt.coordinate, '<div><h2>Coordinates</h2><p>' + prettyCoord + '</p></div>');
    });
    }
```

I used to use unByKey to unlisten the single click event. However, the developers removed this method in OpenLayers 4. Therefore, I am bound to use map.un method. I am trying to use this method, but it is not doing anything. I am doing  `map.un("singleclick", addFullScreenPopups());` for unlistening this event, but it is not doing anything. Why?

Update: I also looked at the signature of .on method and it is given as on(type, listener, opt_this). So I changed my .on method to  `map.on('singleclick', function addFullScreenPopups(evt) {//statements});` and called  `map.un('singleclick',  addFullScreenPopups());` Unfortunately, this didn't help me out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to wrap your callback function in a separate function. Something like that:

```
//here is you callback function
function myCallback(evt){
        var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup({insertFirst: false});
        map.addOverlay(popup);
        var prettyCoord = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'), 2);
        console.log("Pretty Coordinates : "+prettyCoord);
        popup.show(evt.coordinate, '<div><h2>Coordinates</h2><p>' + prettyCoord + '</p></div>');
}
//To bind the event 
map.on('singleclick', myCallback);
//To unbind the event
map.un('singleclick', myCallback);
```

Comment: Why should we pass our callback function when we want to just unbind an event?

Comment: Because you may bind multiple functions to a single event. So lets say you attach two different functions on `singleclick` event  and  now you want to remove the first function but keep executing the second one.

Answer (score 8):

In case you would like to keep your registering function in its current form, the `on` method in OpenLayers returns the unique key assigned to the event listener function, which can be used with the `ol.Observable.unByKey` global function.

```
function addFullScreenPopups(){
  var evtKey = map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup({insertFirst: false});
    map.addOverlay(popup);
    var prettyCoord = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'), 2);
    console.log("Pretty Coordinates : "+prettyCoord);
    popup.show(evt.coordinate, '<div><h2>Coordinates</h2><p>' + prettyCoord + '</p></div>');
  });
  return evtKey;
}

var key = addFullScreenPopups(); //Register the listener and save the key.
ol.Observable.unByKey(key); //Remove the listener. You don't have to know about the map object and the click event, it is handled by OL internally.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript's [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) function to remove the listener.

```
map.removeEventListener('singleclick');
```

Comment: Albeit I like your point, there are some misconceptions in your answer preventing me from upvoting it. 1) OL's `removeEventListener` is not a native JS function, OL successfully implemented the DOM 2 `EventTarget` interface. 2) if you don't specify the listener function, OL removes the last one associated to the event type on the appropriate object. See the [source code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.1.1/src/ol/events/eventtarget.js#L143).