# How to unlisten an event in OpenLayers 6?

Tags: openlayers, react, event-listener

[This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241487/how-to-unlisten-an-event-in-openlayers-4) is similar to mine but it's not working for me.
This is an on-click function for the identifier button. This function will trigger a popup design function when the user clicks on some feature on the map. I want this click functionality on that feature to be suppressed when the user clicks the identifier button a second time. This means the identifier button should act like a start-stop switch.

This function is inside `useEffect()` and the `#IdentifierClick` is the id for the button in `return{}` part which will trigger the click event.

```
function addFullScreenPopups(){

            if ((enableIdentify == false)) 
                {
                    var singleclick_key = initialMap.on('singleclick', function (evt) 
                    {
                        console.log(evt, "printevt");
                        var myLayerChecked;
                        console.log(layerlist, "printlayerlist");
                        for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                            layerlist[1].values_.layers.array_[i].values_.layers.array_.forEach(arrayItem => {
                                myLayerChecked = arrayItem.state_.visible;
                                console.log("myLayerChecked", myLayerChecked);
                                if (myLayerChecked == true) {
                                    document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = '<p class="identifier_p"><b>Identifier Details</b></p>';
                                    console.log("My Array Data", arrayItem.values_.source)
                                    designHtml(evt, arrayItem.values_.source, arrayItem.values_.title);
                                    enableIdentify = true;
                                }
                                else {
                                    console.log("No Layer is checked");
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    })
                    return singleclick_key;
                }
                else 
                {

                }

        }

        $("#IdentifierClick").on("click", function () {
            console.log("working");
            clicktimes++;
            console.log("Clicked:",clicktimes);

            if(clicktimes<2) 
            {
                var key = addFullScreenPopups();
            }
            else {
                initialMap.unByKey(key);
            }

        });
```

The `intialMap.on('singleclick',function())` is initiated and its event key is stored in variable key. Then `initialMap.unByKey(key)` is used to unbind the event. But `initialMap.unByKey(key)` is giving me error as `Uncaught TypeError: initialMap.unByKey is not a function`. What are some solutions?

Comment: See correct method and syntax for ol6: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#un

Comment: @TomazicM `un` only works if the listener is a named function. If you have keys `unByKey` is the correct method but is is not a method of an object, it must be imported using `import {unByKey} from 'ol/Observable'` or with the full build syntax use `ol.Observable.unByKey(key)`

Comment: @Mike Thanks for clarification. I knew that (I'm using it), just forgot about it.

Comment: I have used the `initialMap.un` method to successfully disable the `singleclick` event. But now if I want to bind the event again using `intialMap.on` the clicks don't work on the map. Any solutions for this? @Mike